# How to merge multiple RTF files into one RTF in C#

Tags: c#, rtf

I'm trying to merge multiple rtf documents into one. the size of the merged is increased (size of all the documents) but when i open, i could see only the first RTF file content only.

```
string srcpath = @"C:\CSI\RTFtest\src\";
        string despath = @"C:\CSI\RTFtest\dest\single.rtf";
        string content = "";
        List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(srcpath, "*.rtf"));
        StreamReader read;
        if (files.Count > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                String filename = files[i];
                content = File.ReadAllText(filename);                    
                //content = content + read.ReadToEnd();
                File.AppendAllText(despath, content.ToString());
                File.AppendAllText(despath, System.Environment.NewLine);


            }
```

Comment: I doubt you can just concatenate the files like that. You'll need to understand and combine the content to some degree, even if it's just move the content from the second file into the outermost braces of the first. There are likely libraries that'll simplify this for you.

Answer (score 0):

RTF Files are not text files. You can't jsut concatenate the text as there are headers and other structures involved. You can read all about this spec here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/86999 (yuck).
You can use a TextRange object if you're using wpf, load the first file into it then append each additional file's content. Or you could read files into richtextbox objects in winforms and append the content (how to load: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z7hy77a.aspx).
I guess you could use TextBox1.Rtf = TextBox1.Rtf + textBox2.rtf untill all are loaded since the rtf property is the string with rtf encoding in it.

Comment: Actually, ignore this, this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628553/merge-rtf-files

Comment: TextBox1.Rtf = TextBox1.Rtf + textBox2.rtf  is not working  but TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text+ TextBox2.Text  is displaying the 2nd rtf

Comment: Cool, sounds like you've got a solution then.

Comment: SelectedRtf is the magic property here.  Lets you isolate the text from the RTF header.  Use SelectAll() first.  Text seems to work but doesn't copy any of the RTF markup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder`. You can append RTF to RTF.

Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi");
sb.Append(@"...
HPIrichTextBox.Rtf = sb.ToString();
```